# Regex to find two strings within a pipe delimited string

Tags: .net, regex, delimited

I need to find a match within the delimited string if the following two words appear between the pipes: **apple** and **red**

Example string 1 (should give a match):

```
|big blueberries blue|awesome lemon yellow|apple nice delicious red|
```

Example string 2 (should not give match):

```
|big blueberries apple|awesome lemon yellow|nice delicious red|
```

RegEx tried:

```
^.*?apple.*?red.*?
```

Which (kind of) works, but not sure how to include the pipe logic i.e. search between pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2 words in that order have to be between 2 pipes:

```
^[^|\r\n]*\|.*?\bapple\b[^|\r\n]*\bred\b[^|\r\n]*\|.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^|\r\n]*\|` Match any char except `|` or a newline and then match `|`
- `.*?` Match as least as possible
- `\bapple\b` Match the word apple
- `[^|\r\n]*` Match optional chars other than `|` or a newline
- `\bred\b` Match the word red
- `[^|\r\n]*\|` Match any char except `|` or a newline and then match `|`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%7c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5c%7c.*%3f%5cbapple%5cb%5b%5e%7c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5cbred%5cb%5b%5e%7c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5c%7c.*&i=%7cbig+blueberries+blue%7cawesome+lemon+yellow%7capple+nice+delicious+red%7c%0d%0a%7cbig+blueberries+apple%7cawesome+lemon+yellow%7cnice+delicious+red%7c%0d%0a%0d%0a%7cbig+blueberries+blue%7cawesome+lemon+yellow%7capple+nice+delicious+red%0d%0aapple+nice+delicious+red%7c&o=m)

If the order does not matter, you could use a capture group for either apple or red, and match the same word again, asserting that is using a negative lookhead and a backreference that it is not already matched:

```
^[^|\r\n]*\|.*?\b(apple|red)\b[^|\r\n]*\b(?!\1)(?:apple|red)\b[^|\r\n]*\|.*
```

See another [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%7c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5c%7c.*%3f%5cb%28apple%7cred%29%5cb%5b%5e%7c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5cb%28%3f!%5c1%29%28%3f%3aapple%7cred%29%5cb%5b%5e%7c%5cr%5cn%5d*%5c%7c.*&i=%7cbig+blueberries+blue%7cawesome+lemon+yellow%7capple+nice+delicious+red%7c%0d%0a%7cbig+blueberries+apple%7cawesome+lemon+yellow%7cnice+delicious+red%7c%0d%0a%0d%0a%7cbig+blueberries+blue%7cawesome+lemon+yellow%7capple+nice+delicious+red%0d%0aapple+nice+delicious+red%7c%0d%0a%0d%0a%7cbig+blueberries+blue%7cawesome+lemon+yellow%7cred+nice+delicious+apple%7c&o=m)

Comment: Could you please give an example if order does not matter (between the 2 pipes). Thank you!

Comment: @apples-oranges If the order does not matter, you could for example use `^[^|\n]*\|.*?\b(apple|red)\b[^|\n]*\b(?!\1)(?:apple|red)\b[^|\n]*\|.*` https://regex101.com/r/7UeNnW/1

Comment: Sorry for the late reply -- what if I want to match only one word in between the pipes.  I assume this will work?: `^[^|\r\n]*\|.*?\bapple\b[^|\r\n]*`  Thanks again!

Comment: @apples-oranges That is correct, if you want to be sure that there is an ending pipe you can also extend it to `^[^|\r\n]*\|.*?\bapple\b[^|\r\n]*\|`

Answer (score 0):

If  "apple" and "red" need to appear between the pipes, use:

```
^.*?apple[^|]*red.*?
```

**Explanation:** Force any characters between "apple" and "red" not to be a pipe symbol `|`. You can also get rid of the greedy match `?`, then.

See for yourself at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NbUNfO/2)...